# why cant i get spring load time weaving to work

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-annotations, load-time-weaving

i have been trying to get an example @Configuration build to work (in groovy)  so i can trigger dependency injection outwith a spring container but all i get is error about the -javaagent which i cant seem to fix

I have a beanConfig class like this

`@Configuration 
    @EnableSpringConfigured  // should turn on  AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect 
    @EnableLoadTimeWeaving (aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)  // switch on for this context
    class BeanConfig {`

then a sample class i will call new on and try and get the injection oustide the spring container, where the diSource bean is declared in the above configuration class

`
    @Configurable (autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE, dependencyCheck=true)
    class ExtDI {
    @Autowired DISource diSource

```
def say () {
    println "ExtDI : diSource set as " + diSource.name
}
}
```

`

in my sampler class i call this to try and trigger the injection

`
    ...
    static void main (String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(/*BeanConfig.class*/)
        ctx.scan ("com.softwood")
        ctx.refresh ()
    ....

```
    //trigger LTW injection
    ExtDI ext = new ExtDI()
    ext.say()
```

`

on the class path i have aspectjeaver-1.6.10.jar, aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar, spring-xxx-3.1.4.jars, etc 
heres my gradle depdency listing

`dependencies {
    compile     'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.7'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile     "org.springframework:spring-core:${spring_version}"
    compile     "org.springframework:spring-beans:${spring_version}"
    compile     "org.springframework:spring-context:${spring_version}"
    compile     "org.springframework:spring-aspects:${spring_version}"
    compile     "org.springframework:spring-aop:${spring_version}"
    compile     "org.springframework:spring-instrument:${spring_version}"
    compile     "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.10"
    compile     "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.6.10"
    compile     "cglib:cglib:2.2"
    }`

in the eclipse project runtime for the vm args i have 

    `-javaagent:C:/Users/802518659/aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar`

and have tried same with spring-instrument-3.1.4.jar and had same problem.

when i run the project i get this error

`

```
Oct 19, 2013 4:02:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@492ff1: startup date [Sat Oct 19 16:02:40 BST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 19, 2013 4:02:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@11bedb0: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,beanConfig,willsBean,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.SpringConfiguredConfiguration,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration,loadTimeWeaver,publicBean,privateBean,publicBeanWithDI,myDISource,diTarget]; root of factory hierarchy
Oct 19, 2013 4:02:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@11bedb0: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,beanConfig,willsBean,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.SpringConfiguredConfiguration,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration,loadTimeWeaver,publicBean,privateBean,publicBeanWithDI,myDISource,diTarget]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/context/annotation/LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
...
```

`

which tells me that my application can't instrument the java classloader  - despite the fact i start it with the -javaagent:spring-instrument-xxx or aspectjweaver.jar - both fail

So what am i doing wrong - this is really beginning to bother me - i can get ordinary injection within the context to work (no LTW) but really wanted to get this injection outside the container to work

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

took some time but figured out where it was going wrong

corrected on another post on spring forums see 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/724426-cant-get-aspectj-load-time-weaving-to-work

also i added a longer note to my blog here

http://willwoodman.wordpress.com/